# Single Sign On (SSO) Using JWT for cross domain in .net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, single-sign-on, jwt

I have a two sites on different hosts. Let's use domain1.com and domain2.com. We need a single sign-on solution, which means if a user authenticates on domain1.com, we want him to also be authenticated on domain2.com, automatically . passing the user details in jWT token .!

Questions 1: How can redirect to the domain1.com to domain2.com with JWT ,our main use case is not cross-domain requests, it's having a single sign-on solution!

Comment: What do you mean by `redirect to the domain1.com to domain2.com with JWT`? For SSO, it means when you login the domain1, when you request the resource in domain2, there is no need to login again.

Comment: The both domain have different login process, User login to the domain1.com and request to access the domian2.com ,  domain2.com need for the user information for login.

Answer (score -1):

There is no single resource for SSO regarding .Net Core using JWT.
This is annoying.

Comment: This is not an answer! Post it as a comment please!